# when I am trying to send message to the group via xmpp I am getting this error in windows phone 8

Tags: windows, xmpp

when I am trying to send message to the group via xmpp I am getting this error in windows phone 8

```
<error code="406" type="modify"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></message>
```

Comment: Could you include the message you're sending?

Comment: Yes I just sent "Hello"

Comment: Please include the entire XML stanza you're sending to the server.

Comment: I found that there a problem with presence. I need to send presence to xmpp server. But I don't know how to do in windows phone

Comment: <message type="error" id="6b7eb41c-0de7-4b4f-a17e-71da623f7dc3" from="windowsphone@conference.105.131.79.171" to="528@105.131.79.171/1bf4748e">
  <body>Hello</body>
<error code="406" type="modify"><not-acceptable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></message>

Comment: Done !!! it was just problem with presence